# css menu or script don't work on ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, menu

thanks to anyone that can help me!

I have a css menu on a php and I've used this script on the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPic (whichpic) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  document.getElementById('imgContenedor').src = whichpic.href;
  if (whichpic.title) {
      document.getElementById('imgDescripcion').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}
</script>
```

and the menu:

```
<div id="subopciones" class="menudesp">

        <table border="0" id="tabla_submenu" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
    <td id='celda_submenu'><li><a href="" id='opcion_submenu' >Mobiliario Urbano</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano01.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Espectacular Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano02.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Oppi Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano03.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Mupi Urbano Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano04.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Mupi Central Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano05.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Mupi Premium Barcelona</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></td>
    <td id='espacio_submenu'></td>
    <td id='celda_submenu'><li><a href='' id='opcion_submenu' >Transporte</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/transporte01.jpg">&nbsp Buses Urbanos Palma de Mallorca</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/transporte02.jpg">&nbsp Vehículos Promocionales</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></td>
    <td id='espacio_submenu'></td>
    <td id='celda_submenu'><li><a href='productos.php?pant=digital' id='opcion_submenu' >Digital Gran Formato</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/digital01.jpg">&nbsp Pantallas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></td>
    <td id='espacio_submenu'></td>
    <td id='celda_submenu'><li><a href='productos.php?pant=transportes' id='opcion_submenu' >Nieve</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/nieve01.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Vallas Montaña</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/nieve02.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Oppis Montaña</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/nieve03.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Pilonas</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/nieve04.jpg">&nbsp Lonas Montaña</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></td>
    <td id='espacio_submenu'></td>
    <td id='celda_submenu'><li><a href='productos.php?pant=espectacular' id='opcion_submenu' >Zonas de Ocio</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/zonas01.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Parques de Ocio</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/zonas02.jpg">&nbsp Centros Comerciales</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
</div>
```

AND HERE THE CSS

```
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.menudesp li {
    display:block !important;
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000000;
    width:100%;
    height:23px;
    line-height:23px;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    text-align:left;
}



.menudesp li a {
color: #000000;
font-size:10px;
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 180px;
}

.menudesp li a:hover {
color: #000;
}


.menudesp li ul {
display: none;
padding: 10px 0;
position: absolute;
margin: -8px 0px;
}

.menudesp li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

/*
.menudesp li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
padding: 0 20px;
line-height: 30px;
}*/

.menudesp li ul li a{
color: #444;
}

.menudesp li ul li a:hover {
color: #000;
}

.menudesp li a:hover {
color: #000;
}li a:hover {
color: #000;
} {
color: #000;
}lor: #000;
}
```

Here the error [image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/menusx.jpg/)
And it WORKS great on chrome, but no in IE, any ideas??? I really don't know where to look!

Comment: What is the problem with IE? I meant does it not work at all or some part seems to fail?

Comment: Where is the html with the ids **imgContenedor** and **imgDescripcion**? Could you include that as well in your question?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What is it that don't work?

Comment: Clyde Lobo, I mean that the menu doesn't work (it doesn't show the items on it) and also I deleted the "points" of the `<ul>` and on ie appears once again!

Comment: I upload an image where you can see what is wrong, on the left chrome, on the right ie! [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/menusx.jpg/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `innerHTML` property instead of `nodeValue`:

```
function showPic (whichpic) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  document.getElementById('imgContenedor').src = whichpic.href;
  if (whichpic.title) {
      document.getElementById('imgDescripcion').innerHTML = whichpic.innerHTML;
  }
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I did the changes you suggest; same result! it doesn't work in ie! any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was just reading about people complaining about everyone recommending jQuery (or some other javascript framework), but this is exactly what they're used for... to abstract away the inherent differences in javascript implementations.

So without further ado, I present to you, your jQuery solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showPic (whichpic) {

 var wpic = jQuery(whichpic); // make our object jQuerified

 jQuery('#imgContenedor').attr("src", wpic.attr("href"); // Set our image container

 jQuery('#imgDescripcion').html(wpic.html()); // Set our image description

  return false;
}
</script>
```

You could take this a step further, and remove the inline onclick and do...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery("#celda_submenu li<a").click(showPic); // This will bind to all anchor (a) elements nested below an li inside an element with celda_submenu as the id.
</script>
```

Comment: mmmm MIchael, thanks for help, but i'd try what you say, but on ie, dosn't work either

Comment: Did you try just the first part only?  Are you getting any errors?  I may have made a typo.

Comment: yes you had one error, a ) was miss but I saw it on time! ;) but when I use your code instead of mine, I had the same result, ok on chrome, bad on ie!

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  Also can you include your HTML that contains imgContenedor and imgDescripcion?

Comment: I'm using IE 9, and the part of the html, is just `<img id="imgContenedor" src="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano01.jpg" />` i don't know what can be, i was talking with iMoses, and maybe is the css, i put it on my original post!

Comment: i've just reedit my orgiinal post (i delete one ul and change a bit the css)

Comment: ARGH! OH MY GOD!!!! IT WAS JUST I FORGET TO PUT:


    `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

asdassdsaeasd!!!! now i saw that i had other problems but at least that has been solved! THanks a lot to everyone!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why is the ul element defined twice?
And the first time is outside the table.
Your HTML seems to be broken, which may definitely cause differences between browsers.

```
<div id="subopciones" class="menudesp">
        <table border="0" id="tabla_submenu" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
    <td id='celda_submenu'><li><a href="" id='opcion_submenu' >Mobiliario Urbano</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano01.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Espectacular Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano02.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Oppi Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano03.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Mupi Urbano Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano04.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Mupi Central Barcelona</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano05.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Mupi Premium Barcelona</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: mmm thanks for the help iMoses, but I need to put those ul cos if i don't the menus appears all open at the same time (in chrome and on ie)

Comment: It's invalid HTML. Tell me what are you trying to achieve and we might find a solution, but you can't put a table inside of a ul element. That wouldn't fly and will cause different behavior on different browsers.

Comment: Hi iMoses, thanks again! mmm so now I think you are right and maybe the problem is on the css I'm gonna paste the css reediting my post, can you take a look? it would be a big help!!!!

Comment: That would be great! Also you can consider either moving the table inside your first li (child of the first ul) or move the first ul inside your td element. That would keep the same structure while making your HTML valid again.

Comment: no i can't do that cos the code i put it it's not all of them i have a lot of menus more! i just put a part of it... i'm gonna update the code of the html now, including all the menus, you will see (thanks a lot man!)

Comment: any help iMoses¿? i just made some rectifications, i delete de ul that you say and change the css, i'm reediting my post!

Comment: ARGH! OH MY GOD!!!! IT WAS JUST I FORGET TO PUT:


    `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

asdassdsaeasd!!!! now i saw that i had other problems but at least that has been solved! THanks a lot to everyone!!!!!!!